# How to give different color to the selected range in rich text editor?

Tags: javascript, range, selection, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I'm building a custom rich text editor. However, unlike making the selected range bold, italic or underlined, I can't make it different color by just using the wrapping tags. How can I achieve what I want ?

Comment: try css classes?

Comment: For that, I need to wrap it in a span element or something, which I think is not the ideal solution, so I'm seeking if there's a better one.

Comment: how are you changing the text style/decoration without wrapping it in an inline element?

Comment: fwiw, all of the solutions that I've seen that do things like syntax highlight code blocks in html use inline tag wrappers with classes to set the font styles and colors